# How to adopt different colors of the geom_smooth line based on its gradient?

Tags: r, date

Assuming I have a data frame as follows and did a `ggplot` with the linear line for the last few periods of my data, I was wondering if it's possible to apply a different colour to the geom_smooth line based on its gradient (e.g. green if its upward trend, red if downward trend and black of the trend is roughly constant)?

```
Date <- as.yearqtr(seq(as.Date("2005/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"), by = "quarter"))
GDP<- as.vector(sample(1000:4000,length(Date), replace=T))
df <- data.frame(Date, GDP)
ggplot(df, aes(Date, GDP)) + geom_line(colour="darkblue") + 
  geom_smooth(data=subset(df, Date >= as.numeric(df$Date[length(Date)-8])), method="lm") + 
  xlab("Date") + ylab("GDP") + ggtitle("Nominal GDP")
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best person to answer this. But it seems to me that maybe if you run `lm` for your data, extract the coeffecients (which are the line slopes), and put them in your data as a column, it should be easy.

```
model <- lm(y~x, df) ## You'll have to run your lm here.
model$coeffecients ## Can be used to extract the slope of each line.
```

After you figre that out, something like this would make sense to me:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Date, GDP)) +
geom_line(colour = "darkblue") +
geom_smooth((data=subset(df, Date >= as.numeric(df$Date[length(Date)-8])),
             method="lm", 
             colour = coefficient) +
scale_fill_gradient2(high = "green", 
                    low = "red", 
                    mid = "black", 
                    midpoint = 0)
```